# I can (asdf:load-system :foo), but asdf still complains that '"foo" doesn't designate a package'

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp, asdf

Trying to finally start using asdf for my lisp doodles, I tried setting up a simple example. The files are

```
; contents of example.asd
(asdf:defsystem "example"
   :name "example"
   :depends-on ("foo")
   :components ((:file "example")))
```

and

```
; contents of example.lisp
(defpackage :example
   (:use :cl :asdf :foo))
(in-package :example)
```

(where "foo" is actually "cl-wav", but the problem persists with any of the packages I have installed locally).

Now, even though running

```
(asdf:load-system :foo)
```

works, when I try to evaluate

```
(asdf:make :example)
```

I get this error message:

```
The name "FOO" does not designate any package.
```

What am I doing wrong?

For context, my asdf-version is "3.1.5", the package "foo" is installed with (the latest version of) quicklisp, and all of this takes place in SBCL 1.3.20.

Comment: The name of the system is not necessary the same as the name of any package in the system. The system `cl-wav` has a package named `WAV`, so you need to use `(:use :wav ...)` to use it.

Comment: You were right, that solved it! I still don't know why it didn't work with "zpng" instead of "cl-wav" when I tried this earlier; it now works with "zpng" too. Must have missed something.

Comment: Please make an answer, @jkiiski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASDF systems are a different thing from packages. A system is simply a way to group a bunch of files together in a single application or a library, which can be easily compiled, loaded, tested or installed with Quicklisp. There may be multiple packages in a single system (or even none, although that would be strange). Usually libraries have a "main" package with the same name as the system, but that isn't mandatory.

In this case, the system `cl-wav` defines a package named `WAV`, so you need to use that in your package definition. It might have been better for the library author to name the package `CL-WAV` with `WAV` as a nickname, but they didn't do so.

```
(defpackage :example
  (:use :cl :asdf :wav))
```